# Try to use JDBC connection got access denied

Tags: java, mysql, cmd, connection, localhost

Hey guys : I tried to use JDBC connection to mySQL database, I got the error message as following: "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)] with root cause". I have no problem using commend line "mysql -u root -p" to access mySQL and I'm quite sure I set the right password. Is that anything for my setting as following:

```
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_schema");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("mypassword");
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: just, what you sure you are connecting on good schema ?

Comment: >I have no problem using commend line "mysql -u root -p" to access mySQL < Are you sure you're running that on the same machine as the one you're attempting to run your Java on and the password's the same?